# How to turn off specific php warning in Emacs

Tags: php, emacs

Each time I save .php file this buffer pop up although I didn't make any mistakes.

```
(node:2206) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'INVALID_ALT_NUMBER' of module exports 
inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:2206) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'INVALID_ALT_NUMBER' of module exports 
inside circular dependency
```

But when I try making mistakes, it goes like this

```
(node:2779) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'INVALID_ALT_NUMBER' of module exports 
inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:2779) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'INVALID_ALT_NUMBER' of module exports inside circular dependency
[error] hamming.php: SyntaxError: Parse Error : syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ';' on line 13
[error]   11 |     // }
[error]   12 |     throw new InvalidArgumentException('DNA strands must be of equal length.')
[error] > 13 | }
[error]   14 |
```

Is there a way to only show [error] warning?

The buffer name that created automatically each time I save a PHP file is

```
*format-all-errors*
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the cause of that problem.
Because I enable doom layer

```
;; (format +onsave)  ; automated prettiness
```

after I comment it, the popup buffers not open anymore.